# How to convert a struct into a flat array of paths?

Tags: go

If for example I have a struct such as:

```
type Example struct {
  Foo string
  Bar string
  Baz struct{
    A int
    B string
  }
  Qux []string
}
```

What would be the best approach to convert it into a flat slice of strings representing the dot path to each struct field?

I want an output that looks like the following slice:

```
["Example.Foo", "Example.Bar", "Example.Baz.A", "Example.Baz.B", "Example.Qux.0", "Example.Qux.1"]
```

The exact structs will be known at compile time. Also, the conversion from struct to a flat list is in a hot path so performance will be an important consideration.

Any hints would be appreciated!

Comment: Reflection is the only way to access the name of fields at runtime for inclusion in a string.   Consider using map[string]interface{} if you want strings to identify your values.

Comment: The struct will be decoded from a marshalled protobuf so that my not be an option. Do you think the runtime penalty for using reflection is worth worrying about?

Comment: Not really.  I would worry more about the code being a lot more complicated.  I agree with blackburn's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to code it yourself, with reflection.

This is a demonstrative function that prints the output you provided:

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
    "reflect"
    "strconv"
)

type Example struct {
    Foo string
    Bar string
    Baz struct{
        A int
        B string
    }
    Qux []string
}

func main() {
    example := Example{Qux: []string{"a", "b"}}
    t := reflect.ValueOf(example)
    prefix := t.Type().Name()
    fmt.Println(ToPathSlice(t, prefix, make([]string, 0)))
}

func ToPathSlice(t reflect.Value, name string, dst []string) []string {
    switch t.Kind() {
    case reflect.Ptr, reflect.Interface:
        return ToPathSlice(t.Elem(), name, dst)

    case reflect.Struct:
        for i := 0; i < t.NumField(); i++ {
            fname := t.Type().Field(i).Name
            dst = ToPathSlice(t.Field(i), name+"."+fname, dst)
        }

    case reflect.Slice, reflect.Array:
        for i := 0; i < t.Len(); i++ {
            dst = ToPathSlice(t.Index(i), name+"."+strconv.Itoa(i), dst)
        }

    default:
        return append(dst, name)
    }
    return dst
}
```

Will print:

```
[Example.Foo Example.Bar Example.Baz.A Example.Baz.B Example.Qux.0 Example.Qux.1]
```

Note that:

- reflection comes at a performance penalty; if you are concerned about this, you should profile the relevant code path to see if it's a deal breaker
- the above code is contrived, for example it doesn't handle maps, it doesn't handle `nil`, etc.; you can expand it yourself
- in your desired output, the indices of slice/array fields is printed. Slices don't have inherent length as arrays. In order to know the length of slices, you have to work with `reflect.Value`. This IMO makes the code more awkward. If you can accept not printing indices for slices, then you can work with `reflect.Type`.

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/isNFSfFiXOP